# Painting Issue when selecting file using CFileDialog

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, winpe

I am facing an issue using `CFileDialog` in my code.

When I call the `CFileDialog` from ModalDialog, to select a file.
My whole ModalDialog background gets erased once the current view is exited and reopened.

Procedure followed:

1. Main Dialog
2. Opened ModalDialog
3. Opened `CFileDialog` for selecting file
4. Exit ModalDialog
5. Reopen ModalDialog [Background gets erased]

**Note :** This issue happens only if I select a file. 
If I click on Cancel in the `CFileDialog`. There is no issue.

PFB, the code snippet of my `CFileDialog` use:

```
//This is the code to Open the DoModal dialog from MainWindow 
//
void CCommonDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{

    COSDADlg dlg;
    //m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
    if (nResponse == IDOK)
    {

    }
    else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
    {
        // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
        //  dismissed with Cancel
    }

}

// This is the code for open CFileDialog from ModalDialog to save file
//
void COSDADlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{

        CFileDialog dlgFile(FALSE);

        CString fileName;
        dlgFile.GetOFN().lpstrFile = fileName.GetBuffer(FILE_LIST_BUFFER_SIZE);
        dlgFile.GetOFN().nMaxFile = FILE_LIST_BUFFER_SIZE;


        INT_PTR nResult = dlgFile.DoModal();
        fileName.ReleaseBuffer();   

}

//This is the code to paint the background image for ModalDialog
//
void COSDADlg::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    Graphics    graph(dc.m_hDC);
    CRect rt;
    GetWindowRect(&rt);
    graph.DrawImage(m_pImage, (INT)0, (INT)0,  (INT)rt.Width() , (INT)rt.Height() );
    DefWindowProc(WM_PAINT, (WPARAM)dc.m_hDC, (LPARAM)0);

}
```

Comment: `DefWindowProc(WM_PAINT, (WPARAM)dc.m_hDC, (LPARAM)0);` looks fishy to me, try to remove it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz : I tried your suggestion of removing the DefWindowProc fucntion. But, it is not solving the issue,

From the looks of it, I don't think that this is an issue with the painter. Seems more related to CFileDialog.

Just to re-iterate, this Does Not happen when I just cancel the CFileDialog. Rather only when I select a file from it and save.

Comment: There is a bug in your code, but we cannot see it. The fact that you are calling into the window procedure from your `WM_PAINT` handler displays an alarming lack of understanding, how MFC works. I would be surprised, if this were your only bug.

Comment: @IInspectable : Ok. Let me rectify that as well. One more point, if it could be of any significance, is that this issue occurs only when used in WinPE.
And, works fine on the normal window os(windows 7 or windows 8).

Comment: That's probably not significant. Your code exhibits undefined behavior, and it has different observable effects on different platforms. *"Appearing to work just fine"* is a legal form of undefined behavior. It's still undefined. Without a [mcve] there's nothing we can do, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Found the reason behind the issue.

When we save/select the file using CFileDialog, the default behavior is to change the WorkingDirectory of the running process.

Due to this, the background image could not be found in the new location and Hence background getting erased.

In order to ensure that this does not happen, we need to use the OFN_NOCHANGEDIR flag in CFileDialog, which retains the working directory.